# Encoded UUID via DjangoJSONEncoder, how to decode it back?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I'm using a JSONField, and to properly serializer a UUID I'm using the DjangoJSONEncoder class:

```
from uuid import uuid4

from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from .models import JsonTestModel

sample_uuid = uuid4()
encoder = DjangoJSONEncoder()
encoded_uuid = encoder.encode(sample_uuid)
test = JsonTestModel.objects.create(extra_data={"encoded_uuid":encoded_uuid})
```

When I access test.extra_data it returns a dict:

```
{"encoded_uuid": '"9e56a5aa-49c8-4ce9-b035-2f0d840fb5de"'}
```

But if since this value is now a string I cannot query the database using it.
It returns:

```
raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
```

Ok, that's expected since I'm working with a string, not a UUID anymore.
But if I try to decode it back to UUID:

```
from uuid import UUID

decoded_uuid = UUID('"9e56a5aa-49c8-4ce9-b035-2f0d840fb5de"')
```

this error appears:

```
    raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
```

So, how can I decode it back to UUID?

Comment: You try to decode a quoted UUID. Remove the inner double quotes.

Comment: Shoot, I didn't notice that. using .split('"')[1] actually gave the correct string. Thanks

Comment: Your code should raise a SyntaxError. Please check your code before posting!

Comment: You're right, swapped a : for a = inside the json